# Is there a way to trigger a Bot Action Dialog in a target Conversation through Proactive Notifications?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I have a Virtual Assistant Bot and Skill Bot setup, created from the VA and Skill Templates found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions). I am sending a proactive notification , which has to be handled on the Virtual Assistant, and trigger an Action in the Skill Bot. I am facing an issue where I am only able to send a message using SendActivityAsync() method, but unable to trigger any further steps in the target conversation. Is there a way to trigger an Action in the target Conversation, after getting the target Conversation ID from the Proactive State accessor?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: @ranusharao We slightly modified our approach to fetch the proactive conversation id from the stored Proactive state data and post an event acvitity directly to the target conversation.